# how to sync email client between ubuntu and windows for seamless use of mails and archives

Tags: windows, sync, email

I am looking for an email client which offers seamless integration of (offline) mails when used from linux (ubuntu 12.04) and windows 7. Being a windows user till now, I have been using Outlook and have couple of accounts configured in it, and then there are some backup .pst files created using outlook in windows.

going forward, i would be using linux most of the time and was wondering if there are good clients which work like outlook - offering offline viewing of emails, and backing up in formats like pst. I know linux maynot use pst to backup email files, but was wondering if this can be achieved.

basically, i will be using mail client most of the time in ubuntu to read and archive emails. now, when i log into windows for other work, i want to be able to access the same offline mails and archive emails from there as well, and any new mails that i download/send from within windows should be synchronised so that when i log in to ubuntu later i can easily resume with email works without any additional sync.

hope the requirement is clear. please suggest a mail client compatible for such use with both ubuntu and windows.

cheers!

Comment: Mozilla Thunderbird, will run in Windows and Ubuntu.  I tried having them share configuration files and a database once though and it was somewhat buggy.  You might have more luck just sharing the database but I'm not sure.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to read this http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sharing_a_profile_between_Windows_and_Linux

When i still ran windows, i did share the profile between two of those OSes. But as adempewolff has said it's almost impossible to share configuration files, it is also important to note that the cache wasn't being transferred for me, so the directories within thunderbird were reporting incorrect number of new files.

To find the profile on your Ubuntu machine you need to go to `~/.thunderbird` directory and you'll see some weirdly named catalog, that is your profile. What you can do is install Thunderbird under Windows, find your profile there, and then create a link to that directory in your Ubuntu install.